# Dual boot - ubuntu showing as an option in boot menu, but when selected boots into windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu from a USB drive following instructions. Everything was fine, the system ran fine. But now when I reboot the computer and enter the Boot menu, despite ubuntu being an option, when I select it and press Enter, I still get booted to Windows 10.

I have tried disabling Secure Boot, didn't help.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What brand/model system?  What version of Ubuntu? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version (Option 2) with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/